# Select Children

Tags: xml, xpath

I am working through parsing an xml document to load to another system. I've run across an issue with the XML file that has thrown a wrench into things.

The xml file looks like this:

```
<Project:Application  
xmlns:Budget="http://com.gff/Budget"   
xmlns:Budget1="http://com.gff/Budget123"   
xmlns:Project="http://com.gff/Project"   
xmlns:header="http://com.gff/Header">   
<header:SubmissionHeader>  
    <header:Name>Application Name</header:Name>  
    <header:Number>PRJ12345</header:Number>  
    <header:Title>XML File Parse</header:Title>  
</header:SubmissionHeader>  
<Project:Forms>  
    <Budget123:Budget123>  
        <Budget1:ID>12345</Budget1:ID>  
        <Budget1:Type>Project A</Budget1:Type>  
    </Budget123:Budget123>  
    <Budget123:Budget123>  
        <Budget1:ID>6789</Budget1:ID>  
        <Budget1:Type>Project B</Budget1:Type>  
    </Budget123:Budget123>  
    <Budget123:Budget123>  
        <Budget1:ID>01234</Budget1:ID>  
        <Budget1:Type>Project C</Budget1:Type>  
    </Budget123:Budget123>  
</Project:Forms>
```

Here is the code I am executing to throw the data into variables and load via a webservice to my application:

```
<gel:script 
xmlns:core="jelly:core"  
xmlns:j="jelly.core"  
xmlns:gel="jelly:com.niku.union.gel.GELTagLibrary"  
xmlns:x="jelly:org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.xml.XMLTagLibrary"  
xmlns:util="jelly:util"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<!-- *************************************************************  -->
<!-- Program:  Parse XML Application                                -->
<!-- ************************************************************   -->
<gel:log message="Start Xml File Parse Test" />  
<x:parse var="RemoveNameSpace">  
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
        <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>  
        <xsl:template match="*">  
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">  
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>  
            </xsl:element>  
        </xsl:template>  
        <xsl:template match="@*">  
            <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">  
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>  
            </xsl:attribute>  
        </xsl:template>  
        <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">  
            <xsl:copy/>  
        </xsl:template>  
    </xsl:stylesheet>  
</x:parse>  
<x:parse var="xmlRawData" xml="file:///C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Application.xml"  />  
<x:transform var="xmlData" xml= "${xmlRawData}" xslt="${RemoveNameSpace}" />  
<gel:log message="${xmlData.asXML()}" />  
<gel:parse var="gelXmlData">  
    <x:transform xml= "${xmlRawData}" xslt="${RemoveNameSpace}" />  
</gel:parse>  
<gel:set asString="true" select="$gelXmlData//Application/SubmissionHeader/Name/text()" var="Name"/>
<gel:set asString="true" select="$gelXmlData//Application/@Forms/text()" var="Budget"/>
<gel:log>
  Name = ${Name}
  Budget = ${Budget}
</gel:log>
</gel:script>
```

The problem is that for the budget section, each file appears to be named differently. This file, for example, is has a node name of Budget123, the next file has Budget10, the next file is Budget_12. There appears to be no rhyme or reason as to why the namespaces are the way they are. Rather than hardcode the paths to get the values, I want to walk the tree, get each node, and put them into a variable, then substitute the name for the variable to get the values.

I've tried:

```
//Application/Forms/*[starts-with(local-name(),'Budget')]
```

The problem is that returns:

```
<Budget123:Budget123>  
        <Budget1:ID>12345</Budget1:ID>  
        <Budget1:Type>Project A</Budget1:Type>  
    </Budget123:Budget123>  
    <Budget123:Budget123>  
        <Budget1:ID>6789</Budget1:ID>  
        <Budget1:Type>Project B</Budget1:Type>  
    </Budget123:Budget123>  
    <Budget123:Budget123>  
        <Budget1:ID>01234</Budget1:ID>  
        <Budget1:Type>Project C</Budget1:Type>  
    </Budget123:Budget123>  
</Project:Forms>
```

I only want the node name, not everything else, so: Budget123, or whatever it ends up being.

```
select="$gelXmlData//Application/Forms/*[starts-with(local-name(),'Budget')]/ID/text()" var="ID"
```

The above code did work in getting the values for the node Budget, but at the same time, I want to make it dynamic enough to not be dependent on it always starting with Budget.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the prefix `Budget123` in your input XML is not bound and it is not closed properly with `</Project:Application>`.

Not sure I understand what you'd like the output to be, but I'll give it a try:

```
//Application/Forms/*[starts-with(local-name(),'Budget')]/local-name()
```

The result will be

```
Budget123 Budget123 Budget123
```

**NOTE**: The behavior of this path epression depends on the version of XPath you use. I assume that you are using XPath 2.0. Otherwise, you'll need something like

```
local-name(//Application/Forms/*[starts-with(local-name(),'Budget')])
```

However, this will only yield the name of the *first* element that is found.

---

If this covers all child elements of `Forms`, you could simply use

```
//Application/Forms/*/local-name()
```

A version that is independent of namespaces:

```
//*[local-name()='Application']/*[local-name()='Forms']/*[starts-with(local-name(),'Budget')]/local-name()"
```

Comment: The xml not being bound or closed properly is an issue on the scrubbing of the data. The xml file contains proprietary info I didn't want out. Assume it is bound and closed properly. I tried all four solutions and I keep getting the following error:

Comment: You must define an attribute called 'select' for this tag.

Comment: I am also using jelly to create the xml parse and xpath statements, if that matters. It appears the local-name() is an issue, because if I substitute text(), it has no complains. Sorry, a bit new to xpath and this site. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @user4143204 This error indicates that not XPath is at fault, but something upstream of the path expression.